# Rails 4 rewrite of join and group query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my old query:

```
Dispenser.includes(:dispedus).includes(:educations).group('education.name')
```

To reiterate my post title please **rewrite this** to enable the same query in Rails 4.

Put in question form, how can this be rewritten to work in rails 4 **?** **?** **?**

Comment: so... what is your question?

Comment: Thee is no question, it's just informative :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiple independent associations use commas:

```
Dispenser.joins(:dispedus, :educations).group('educations.name')
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-multiple-associations

With a nested join you can write:

```
Dispenser.joins(dispedus: :educations).group('educations.name')
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-single-level

Comment: 2.1.2 :036 > Dispenser.includes(dispedus: educations).group('educations.name')
NameError: undefined local variable or method `educations' for main:Object

Comment: Oops forgot the colon in educations. Fixed the answer!

Comment: Unknown column 'educations.name' in 'group statement': SELECT `dispensers`.* FROM `dispensers`  GROUP BY educations.name

Comment: I tried all the variations of removing s from educations

Comment: Ahh now I remember, the educations relation must be joined to be able to use it in the group clause. I've adjusted the answer.

Comment: I also confirmed my associations by running Dispedu.joins(:education) and Dispenser.joins(:dispedus)

Comment: You'll have to nest the association in the join for it to work. Did you try it?

Comment: I tried your most recent answer

Comment: This works Dispenser.joins(:dispedus, :educations).group('educations.name')

Comment: Yes the answer was updated to that

Comment: Oh, no it only worked with the comma between like in my example.

Comment: Sorry, must've misinterpreted where you said:
> Dispenser has many educations through dispedus

Comment: Please change your answer to I can give you the check :)  You got me on the right track

Comment: Cool, added an extra link too